# automation installation for third party software on winxp workstation

Tags: windows-xp

Hi  I am working in automobile production environment and using the windchill 9.1 application software on winxp clients (500+nos). if windcill has released new patch I need to update the patch for every one. in this process I need to uninstall windchill workgroup manger software (WGM) older version and install new version with patch. so I need to uninstall old version and install new one in sam path ex: c:\abd\ERB-92 .
It is java based installation application , in this process it will ask us to select language after next  then select location to be installed on local drive. then click on then Done. 
now I need to automate this process.

help me out if you know process or application is there

Answer (score 1):

If it is Java you could create an MSI and select all the appropriate registry keys you need to edit.  Even easier if they have an MSI that you can install silently, grab that and use your AD to distribute it or your software distribution of choice.

Creating your own MSI
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/

More information possibly an MSI installer from them.
http://www.appdeploy.com/

Comment: For multiple terminals network deployment, MSI is really the way to go. +1